# Facebook Like Button With Cookie Not Working

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like

I am trying to get a script to load the facebook like button and save a cookie on my user's machine so I can give them a bonus for liking my content, but for some reason it does not seem to work. Once I click like, nothing happens and then when I click like thereafter, the window only opens briefly and closes also without noticeable change. Here is the index.php file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1" /></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/events.js" /></script>

<?PHP
$cookie_values = array(
                'cookie_path' => '/', 
                'cookie_domain' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 
                'cookie_secure' => false, 
                'cookie_httponly' => false, 
                'cookie_lifetime' => time() + 100 * 12 * 30 * 24 * 60, // 100 Years.
                'hash_storage_key' => true,
                'session_lifetime' => 2000, 
                'session_path' => '/', 
                'session_domain' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 
                'session_secure' => false, 
                'session_httponly' => false, 
                'session_start' => true,
                'storage_key' => 'social_like_locker_data'

);

$oLocker = new clsSocialLikeLocker();
$share_url = clsSocialLikeLocker::getCurrentURL();

$isLiked = $oLocker->isLiked($share_url);
?>
  <?PHP if($isLiked == false): ?>
<div class="panels">
    <h2>URL is locked</h2>
    <p>Like to unlock the URL</p>
    <input type="hidden" id="url_request" value="unlock_handler.php?url=<?PHP echo urlencode($share_url); ?>" />


    <!-- Facebook --> 
    <div class="panel" title="Like on Facebook"> 
        <fb:like href="<?PHP echo $share_url; ?>" layout="box_count" action="like" font="arial" show_faces="true" width="48" height="65"></fb:like> 
    </div> 

    <br class="clear" />

</div>
<?PHP endif; ?>

<?PHP if($isLiked == true): ?>
<div class="panels">
        <h2>URL Unlocked</h2>
        <p>Link 1 goes here!</p>
</div>
 <?PHP endif; ?>
```

Here is the locker class

```
<?PHP
/**
 * Social URL Locker
 *
 * @author      Muneeb <m4munib@hotmail.com>
 * @copyright   Muneeb <m4munib@hotmail.com>
 * @twitter     http://twitter.com/#!/muhammadmunib
 */
class clsSocialLikeLocker
{
    /*For Cookie or Session Storage*/
    private $storage_key = 'social_like_locker_data';

    private static $cookie_lifetime = 5000;
    private static $cookie_path = '/';
    private static $cookie_domain = '';
    private static $cookie_secure = false;
    private static $cookie_httponly = false;
    private static $hash_cookie = false;

    private static $session_lifetime = 5000;
    private static $session_path = '/';
    private static $session_domain = '';
    private static $session_secure = false;
    private static $session_httponly = false;
    private static $hash_storage_key = false;

    /**
     * @param array $session_vars An array of values that set how the class functions.
        *   -'cookie_path' _string_: The path where the cookie is to be stored
        *   -'cookie_domain' _string_: The domain the that the cookie resides on
        *   -'cookie_secure' _boolean_: Access the cookie only over an secure connection
        *   -'cookie_httponly' _boolean_: Write to the cookie only over an http(s) connection
        *   -'cookie_lifetime' _int_: The amount of time the cookie is active for
        *   -'hash_cookie' _boolean_ :Hash the cookie to its value is not easily readable
        *   -'hash_session' _boolean: Has a season so its value is not easily readable
        *   -'session_name' _string_ : Name of the current session
        *   -'session_lifetime' _int_: The life time of the session, in seconds
        *   -'session_path' _string_: The path of the session.
        *   -'session_domain' _string_: The domain of the session. Default is current.
        *   -'session_secure'_boolean_: Access the session only over a secure connection
        *   -'session_httponly' _boolean: Writes to the session only over an http connection
        *   -'hash_storage_key' _boolean: Session/Cookie Storage key will be hashed.
        *   -'storage_key' _string: Session/Cookie Key to Store Like Data
     */
    public function __construct($vars = array())
    {
        $defaults = array(
                'cookie_path' => '/', 
                'cookie_domain' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 
                'cookie_secure' => false, 
                'cookie_httponly' => false, 
                'cookie_lifetime' => time() + 30 * 24 * 60, //one month - default
                'hash_storage_key' => true, 
                'session_lifetime' => 2000, 
                'session_path' => '/', 
                'session_domain' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 
                'session_secure' => false, 
                'session_httponly' => false, 
                'session_start' => true,
                'storage_key' => 'social_like_locker_data'
        );

        $vars += $defaults;

        self::$cookie_path = $vars['cookie_path'];
        self::$cookie_domain = $vars['cookie_domain'];
        self::$cookie_secure = $vars['cookie_secure'];
        self::$cookie_httponly = $vars['cookie_httponly'];
        self::$cookie_lifetime = $vars['cookie_lifetime'];

        self::$session_path = $vars['session_path'];
        self::$session_domain = $vars['session_domain'];
        self::$session_secure = $vars['session_secure'];
        self::$session_httponly = $vars['session_httponly'];
        self::$session_lifetime = $vars['session_lifetime'];

        self::$hash_storage_key = $vars['hash_storage_key'];

        $this->storage_key = $vars['storage_key'];

        $this->_initSession();
    }

    private function _initSession()
    {           
        session_set_cookie_params(self::$session_lifetime, self::$session_path, self::$session_domain, self::$session_secure, self::$session_httponly);

         if( !session_id())
            session_start();
    }


    protected function writeSessionData(array $data)
    {
        $_SESSION[$this->getStorageKey()] = $data;

        return $this;
    }

    protected function writeCookieData(array $data)
    {
        $key = $this->getStorageKey();

        $_data =  json_encode($data);

        $_COOKIE[$key] = $_data;
        return setcookie($key, $_data, self::$cookie_lifetime, self::$cookie_path, self::$cookie_domain, self::$cookie_secure, self::$cookie_httponly);

    }

    protected function readSession()
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION[$this->getStorageKey()]))
        {
            return $_SESSION[$this->getStorageKey()];
        }
        else if(isset($_COOKIE[$this->getStorageKey()]))
        {
            return json_decode($_COOKIE[$this->getStorageKey()]);
        }

        return array();
    }

    private $_key = ''; //local code key caching
    private function getStorageKey()
    {
        if($this->_key == '')
        {
            $this->_key = $this->storage_key;
            if(self::$hash_storage_key)
            {
                $this->_key = md5($this->storage_key);
            }
        }

        return $this->_key;
    }

    protected function getLikeData()
    {
        $like_data = array();

        $like_data = $this->readSession();

        return $like_data;
    }

    public function markAsLiked($locked_url)
    {
        if($locked_url == '')
            return false;

        $like_data = $this->getLikeData();

        $like_data[] = md5($locked_url);
        $like_data = array_unique($like_data);

        $this->writeSessionData($like_data)->writeCookieData($like_data);
    }

    public function markAsLocked($locked_url)
    {
        if($locked_url == '')
            return false;

        $like_data = (array)$this->getLikeData();

        $hash_url = md5($locked_url);
        foreach($like_data as $k => $url)
        {
            if($hash_url == $url)
            {
                unset($like_data[$k]);
            }
        }

        $like_data = array_unique($like_data);

        $this->writeSessionData($like_data)->writeCookieData($like_data);
    }

    public function isAnyUrlLiked()
    {
        $like_data = $this->getLikeData();

        if(count($like_data) > 0)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public function isLiked($locked_url = '')
    {
        if($locked_url == '')
        {
            $locked_url = self::getCurrentURL();
        }

        $like_data = $this->getLikeData();

        $locked_url = md5($locked_url);

        if(is_array($like_data) == false)
            return false;

        if(in_array($locked_url, $like_data))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function destroyLikeSession()
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION[$this->getStorageKey()]))
               unset($_SESSION[$this->getStorageKey()]);

        if(isset($_COOKIE[$this->getStorageKey()]))
        {
               unset($_COOKIE[$this->getStorageKey()]);
               $data = array(); // NULL DATA
               return setcookie($this->getStorageKey(), json_encode($data), time() - 4800, self::$cookie_path, self::$cookie_domain, self::$cookie_secure, self::$cookie_httponly);
        }
    }

    public static function getCurrentURL()
    {
         $current_url = 'http';
         if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$current_url .= "s";}

         $current_url .= "://";
         if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") 
         {
                $current_url .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
         } 
         else 
         {
                 $current_url .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
         }

         return $current_url;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Not possible and against Facebook Platform Policy. You are not allowed to give the user anything for liking

Comment: @WizKid Could you share where in the platform policy this is mentioned? I have looked over it twice now and can not find wording pertaining to this?

Comment: 4.5 on https://developers.facebook.com/policy say "Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other actions".

Comment: I see it now. Just to point out though, it is not against the terms to utilize likes/shares to block content, but the context on how it is done is what matters. If you click the little help '?' next to item 5, they have an example blocking features of an app, but allowing unlock of those features via like promotions in a specific fashion. Thanks for the link though, I may have done it the wrong way initially.

Comment: The little ? shows one exception. You are allowed to send invites to friends and when those friends accept the invite you can give something to the person that sent the invite.